# github- Unable to see diff after cherry-picked new feature

Tags: github

I cheery-picked some changes from other commit into my current feature branch successfully. But I am not getting any changes in the terminal after putting ***git diff*** .

Even I tried with git diff --chached . But no luck finding the difference on the change history . Any one's instant help is very much appreciable.

Thanks,